# Scipy.optimize - constraints not giving expected output

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I'm trying to replicate [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tKV24jzZ10s) simple optimisation problem in order to get started with Scipy.optimize.
The problem is a classic product mix-problem, where the objective is to maximize profit given some production and ingredients constraints, in this case it is a coffee shop with three coffee types.

- x0 -> Regular
- x1 -> Latte
- x2 -> Mocha

Constraints:

- x0+x1+x2 <= 500
- x1+x2    <= 350
- x2       <= 125

Objective function

- Maximize x0*1.5 + x1*2.00 + x2*2.25

Here is my code (please note that I run it in a notebook):

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

#profit / cup
Reg = 1.25
Lat = 2.00
Moc = 2.25

#objective function to maximize
def objective(x):
    return (x[0]*Reg + x[1]*Lat + x[2]*Moc)

#constraints
def cons_total_production(x):
    return (sum(x))-500

def cons_choc(x):
    return (x[2])-125

def cons_milk(x):
    return (sum(x[1:]))-350

cons1 = {'type':'ineq', 'fun':cons_total_production}
cons2 = {'type':'ineq', 'fun':cons_choc}
cons3 = {'type':'ineq', 'fun':cons_milk}
cons = [cons1,cons2,cons3]

#boundries
bnds = ((0,None),(0,None),(0,None))

#initial guess
x0 = [250,150,100]

#let scipy do its magic
sol = minimize(objective, x0, constraints=cons, bounds=bnds)
```

This produces the correct output. **How is that even possible when i use scipy minimize?**

```
     fun: 918.7499999999358
     jac: array([ 1.25,  2.  ,  2.25])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 50
     nit: 10
    njev: 10
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([ 150.,  225.,  125.])
```

But when I try to add one more constrain, the output is wrong. If I for instance would make a constrain that states that x0 must be equal to x1, I would change the following and run the model again:

```
def cons_eq(x):
    return x[0]-x[1]

cons4 = {'type':'eq', 'fun':cons_eq}

cons = [cons1, cons2, cons3, cons4]
```

But now my constrain x2<=125 is ignored:

```
     fun: 937.4999999999934
     jac: array([ 1.25,  2.  ,  2.25])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 35
     nit: 7
    njev: 7
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([ 150.,  150.,  200.])
```

**Any suggestions?** thx...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in both your objective function and the constraints. Since you are using scipy's **minimize** function, you must **minimize the negative of the objective function to find the maximum of the function** (It is slightly tricky).

```
#objective function to maximize
def objective(x):
    return -1.0*(x[0]*Reg + x[1]*Lat + x[2]*Moc)
```

You have also incorrectly typed the inequality functions. If you look at the scipy documentation, all inequalities are in the form g(x)>=0. So, for example, if you want x2 <= 125, you must multiply by negative 1 (to switch the inequality), then add 125 which gets: g(x) = 125-x2 >= 0. So for the rest of your constraints:

```
#constraints
def cons_total_production(x):
    return (-1.0*sum(x))+500

def cons_choc(x):
    return (-1.0*x[2])+125

def cons_milk(x):
    return (-1.0*sum(x[1:]))+350
```

Which will give you the outputs:

```
 fun: -918.7499999999989
 jac: array([-1.25, -2.  , -2.25])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
 nfev: 35
 nit: 7
 njev: 7
 status: 0
 success: True
 x: array([ 150.,  225.,  125.])

 fun: -890.62499998809
 jac: array([-1.25, -2.  , -2.25])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
 nfev: 10
 nit: 2
 njev: 2
 status: 0
 success: True
 x: array([ 187.5,  187.5,  125. ])
```

Linear programming is so cool!

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Good catch! To be fair: this is an LP solved by treating it as NLP (including numerical-diff).

Comment: Your right. It might be more efficient to use scipy.optimize.linprog.